# Iterating PHP namespaced objects in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm trying to iterate trough array of objects using `ng-repeat` in Angular. Everything works fine except for an API, which returns json encoded PHP object, which resides in different namespace on server. That leads to situation, where returned object properties contains `\` in name and I can't find the way how to access them while using `{{Namespace\Property}}` syntax in Angular. `\` causes syntax error on client side, even when trying to escape this character doubling it.

Logging JSON-decoded object in browser returns correct contruction, but can't figure the way to read specified property.

Example output returned from API:

```
0: Object
  Auth\Username: admin
  Auth\Domain: acme.org
  Auth\Enabled: true
1: Object
  Auth\Username: guest
  Auth\Domain: acme.org
  Auth\Enabled: false
```

Comment: Try putting 4 back slashes

Comment: @imesha-sudasingha Unfortunately it leads to same error:
`angular.js:13642 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 9-9 [\] in expression [item.Auth\\\\Username]`